# Limits in Github gists

Tags: github, gist

Is there a limit in the size of a GitHub gist or a maximum number of lines?

I am trying to make a gist with a generated file from logs, and receive a 422 validation error once in a while when the logs are getting relatively large.

Comment: Can you share one of those validation errors?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the GitHub web interface has a limit on the size of data that can be uploaded.  What you can do is create a gist with some data that you want (such as a README or a portion of the data), clone it, and then add the rest of the data via Git and push.

Note that if your log is very large, GitHub may not display it all in the web interface for performance reasons.

Having said that, while it is fine to create a gist to share a particular log snippet, in general Git repositories are not a good way to store logs or other automated data, so you wouldn't want to continually push new logs to that gist or otherwise update it in an automated way to show new log entries.

Comment: You noted that Gist files aren't appropriate for storing logs. Do you know of a suitable alternative?

Comment: There are a variety of tools for storing and indexing logs, which are much better for this purpose.  In many cases, simply compressed flat files in a directory is a fine way, but if you go to large scale, then a tool like Splunk may be useful.